# Accessing Vuex Module in JS file

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuejs3, quasar-framework

I am using Quasar framework + Vue3 and importing a module in my Vuex Store. It works fine when I consume it in a Vue file but how can access it from a JS file? I can log the states in the settings module, but everything is blank. It seems like it wasnt initialized yet, but how can I get the initialized and filled up store? Also, when Vuex store is updated, and I try to fetch the updated data from the JS file, it just shows blank/null.

```js
import { createStore } from 'vuex'
import { settings } from './settings'

export default function () {
  const Store = createStore({
    modules: {
      settings
    },
    state: {
      isProdBuild: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    }
  })
  return Store
}
```

```js
import useStore from '../store'

const store = useStore()
export function sample () {
  console.log(store.state.isProdBuild) // this works
  console.log(store.state.settings.sampleParam) // doesnt work, seems like the value isnt initialized
}
```

Help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround for this issue.

In my JS file, I just added a setter function to set the store.

```js
let store = null
export setStore(val) {
   store = val
}

export function sample () {
  console.log(store.state.isProdBuild)
  console.log(store.state.settings.sampleParam)
}
```

Then in my Vue file:

```js
import { onMounted } from 'vue'
import { useStore } from 'vuex'
import { setStore, sample } from 'sample-file.js'

const $store = useStore()

onMounted(() => {
  setStore($store)
})
```

Then calling whatever method from `sample-file.js` that accesses the Vuex store works now and the state is always updated.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it should be way easier. Every state from the different modules would be merged into just a single state of the store, and you should be able to use it just like that:

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex'
import { settings } from './settings'

export default function () {
  const Store = createStore({
    modules: {
      settings
    },
    state: {
      isProdBuild: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    }
  })
  return Store
}
```

```
import useStore from '../store'

export function sample () {
  console.log(store.state.isProdBuild)
  console.log(store.state.sampleParam) // if there's sampleParam in the settings module this should work
}
```